# My usage of SQL COUNT not working as I expect

Tags: sql, count, mariadb

Let's assume we have the following tables

- Owner(OwnerID, BasketID)
- Basket (BasketID, Description)
- Item (ItemID, BaskedID, Name)

Now I want to query the information for all existing Baskets of Owners, so the rows contain:
OwnerID, TotalNumberOfBaskets, TotalNumberOfItems

SELECT OwnerID,
COUNT(Basket.BasketID),
COUNT(Item.ItemID)
FROM Owner
LEFT JOIN Basket USING (BasketID)
LEFT JOIN Item USING (ItemID);

This is definitely not working as I'm always getting the same count for Basket and Items, while a Basket can contain more than 1 Item.
Any idea or hint, what should the correct usage of (COUNT) to get the desired result?

Thanks a lot in advance, and sorry if this is a really trivial question.

Comment: please add GROUP BY OwnerID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the same count for BasketID and ItemID because BasketID is repeated for every itemID in the Basket table.

You should be using DISTINCT to get the BasketID count, so that duplicate BasketIDs won't be considered.

SELECT OwnerID, COUNT(DISTINCT Basket.BasketID), COUNT(Item.ItemID) FROM Owner
LEFT JOIN Basket USING (BasketID) LEFT JOIN Item USING (ItemID);

Comment: Thanks a lot! A DISCTICT was really needed

Answer (score 2):

You need a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT o.OwnerID, COUNT(DISTINCT b.BasketID), COUNT(i.ItemID)
FROM Owner o LEFT JOIN
     Basket b
     USING (BasketID) LEFT JOIN
     Item i
     USING (ItemID)
GROUP BY o.OwnerID;
```